# Adding EventReceiver to Dynamic List

Tags: development, list, event-receivers, assembly-references

I am trying to add a Event Receiver to a list that is dynamically created (by code).
So i cannot add a event receiver on the list directly.

I found a way to attach a Event Receiver to the list by code.

http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/how-to-add-event-receiver-to-sharepoint2010-content-type-programmatically/

Now i just need to know how can i get the Assembly name of the EventReceiver and its public token key.

I tried running the SN.EXE tool giving it the path where the Event Receiver is in the solution but i get an error.

How can i get the Assembly name of the Event Receiver.

Thanks ! Happy Holidays :D

Comment: Assembly Name is usually included in the Elements.xml file...

Comment: if you see `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` instead of assembly information... Then you should open the wsp generated by solution in Zip [Winzip, 7Zip]... See the Elements.xml file in that!

Comment: Let me check it out. If it works you can post as an answer.

Comment: Worked, thanks, post as a answer and i'll fag it as response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly Name is usually included in the Elements.xml file...

If you see `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` instead of assembly information... Then you should open the wsp generated by solution in Zip [Winzip, 7Zip]... See the Elements.xml file in that!